# Neo4J 2.3.3 Cypher query fails on Neo4J 3.0.1 (Unable to load NODE with id)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Works on 2.3.3, doesn't work on 3.0.1 :

```
MATCH PATH=((:DELETE_AFTER_TEST_DeleteNode)-[*0..2]-()) FOREACH (NODE IN NODES(PATH) | DETACH DELETE NODE)
```

Error in Java

> ```
> org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher
> "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"
> ```

Error on browser

> ```
> Unable to load NODE with id 741969
> ```

The following query in the browser returns a node (id: 741968) that is linked to node 741969

```
MATCH (N:DELETE_AFTER_TEST_DeleteNode) RETURN N
```

How do I delete all nodes in a small graph, given a "root" node using ID or a label, without getting a NEO4J 3.0.1 exception?

Thanks

Comment: These are all statements about what happened. What is your question? Please see the guide for [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MATCH PATH=((A:SOME_UNIQUE_LABEL)-[*0..9]-(B)) 
    DETACH DELETE A 
    DETACH DELETE B
```

Using UNWIND and FOREACH result in error while trying to delete the nodes in the PATH